# JAX-RS: [[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public after upgrading to Weblogic 12c

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I recently upgraded our application to Weblogic 12c and am now having issues with a JAX-RS service. The service looks like this:

```
public DocumentMetadataResponseBean postDocument(@Context                                                                                                                                                         final HttpServletRequest request,
                                                     @FormDataParam("doc")                                                                                                                                            final InputStream inputStream,
                                                     @FormDataParam("doc")                                                                                                                                            final FormDataBodyPart formDataBodyPart,
                                                     @PathParam("employeeOid")        @ApiParam("The person uploading the document")                                                                                  final Long employeeOid,
                                                     @QueryParam("person")            @ApiParam("The person which the document is associated with")                                                                   final Long personOid,
                                                     @QueryParam("name")              @ApiParam("The name of the document")                                                                                           final String documentName,
                                                     @QueryParam("personDocId")       @ApiParam(value = "The documentOid for the document to be used. Only if existing document is used for a request",required=false)final Long personDocumentOid,
                                                     @QueryParam("category")          @ApiParam("The category associated with the document (i.e. Birth Certificate)")                                                 final String documentCategory,
                                                     @QueryParam("documentRequestId") @ApiParam(value = "the documentRequestOid associated with the document request",required=false)                                 final Long documentRequestOid,
                                                     @QueryParam("desc")              @ApiParam(value = "A brief description of the document", required=false)                                                        final String description,
                                                     @QueryParam("version")           @ApiParam("The version of the service")                                                                                         final Integer version){
```

The error I get when starting the app up is: `[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public com.test.DocumentMetadataResponseBean com.test.DocumentJaxRsService.postDocument(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart,java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[application/json, application/xml], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.test.DocumentJaxRsService, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@2e52db74]}, definitionMethod=public com.test.DocumentMetadataResponseBean com.test.DocumentJaxRsService.postDocument(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart,java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=doc, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart, source=doc, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Long, source=employeeOid, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Long, source=person, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=name, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Long, source=personDocId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=category, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Long, source=documentRequestId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=desc, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Integer, source=version, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class com.test.DocumentMetadataResponseBean}, nameBindings=[]}']`

I'm using javax.ws.rs-api  2.0.1 and Jersey 2.25. I do have the MultiPartFeature registered as an init param in the Jersey servlet. Everything works fine if I switch back to weblogic 11g, so I'm sure it's some sort of a classpath issue, but I've tried every possible combination of versions that I can think of for these libraries and nothing seems to work.

Comment: The error doesn't match the resource method you are showing. The error shows a method without the HttpServletRequest, while the method in your post has the request.

Comment: Sorry, I pulled the error from a test where I removed the first parameter of the method which is a, HttpServletRequest, but the error remains the same regardless. It complains about the InputStream parameter.

Comment: What happens if you remove the InputStream parameter? You can get that from the FormDateBodyPart